# javascript onmouseover visibility toggle of 3 separate div's

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have three image links show three separate div's (respectively) when onMouseOver.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleVisibility(divid) {
if (divid="1"){
    document.getElementById("1b").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("2b").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("3b").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
else if (divid="2")
{
    document.getElementById("1b").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("2b").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("3b").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
else if (divid="3")
{
    document.getElementById("1b").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("2b").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("3b").style.visibility = "visible";
}
}
</script>
```

With these onMouseOver events used on all three anchor tags.

```
onmouseover="toggleVisibility('1');"
onmouseover="toggleVisibility('2');"
onmouseover="toggleVisibility('3');"
```

HOWEVER,

All 3, when onMouseOver, show **1a**. And that is all it does.

1a does not go hidden when the other 2 are rolled over and 2a + 3a do not show at all.

Thanks

HTML + CSS:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div style="width:910px;height:300px;margin:0;padding:0;">
<div id="1b">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="2b">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="3b">&nbsp;</div>
<a href="#" onmouseover="toggleVisibility('1');" class="1"></a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="toggleVisibility('2');" class="2"></a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="toggleVisibility('3');" class="3"></a>
</div>
</div>

#wrapper {
width: 896px;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

#1b {
width:303px;
height:150px;
visibility:hidden;
float:left;
background-color:#DED6C5;
}

.1 {
float:left;
height:130px;
width:303px;
display:block;
background-image:url('images/organizational.jpg');
}
```

I modified the names in this post to "1,2,3,1b,2b,3b" to clean it up and be easier to understand.

The CSS for the others is the same as 1 and 1b just with the names changed.

Comment: For this question, it is difficult to provide an answer without seeing the relevant HTML.

Comment: add onmouseout event to return visibility of elements

Comment: Could it be because you haven't specified any dimensions for `2b` and `3b`? Couldn't spot any thing else.

Comment: @techfoobar the CSS for 2b and 3b is in the code, I just didnt post them because they're styled the same as 1b. Same for 2 & 3 with 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in your condition.

When using `if`, valid operator are `||` `&&` `==` `===` `<` `>` `<=` `>=` but you are using `=`.

Try using `==` and it should work.

**EDIT :**

[Anthony Hessler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16777826/2324107) added a good optimisation for your code, you should check it out!

Comment: I did miss it until I created a fiddle!

Comment: I get it, CSS won't work if you start your `class` or `id` by a number.

Comment: Here a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/L4Ghm/1/ . I spoted 3 errors. 1: script tag must be in `head`. 2: the `==` mus be in `if( x == y)`. 3: `style.visible` need only 1 `=`. I hope it will work for you after!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer about the correct conditional formatting, I'd suggest updating your visibility toggle function to reduce the amount of repeated code, which makes it easier to add more dive, should the need arise. Something like this should work quite well for you, as it loops through the number of divs you have, and does 1 conditional check to see if the passed-in number matches the loop iteration value, and sets visibility accordingly.

```
function toggleVisibility(divid) {
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < 4; i += 1) {
        if (divid === i) {
            document.getElementById(i + "b").style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
            document.getElementById(i + "b").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nothing major but you can declare your `var i` in the for : `for(var i = 1;...)`

Comment: I know. It's all personal preference. I like var blocks rather than littering them throughout all of my code :-)

Comment: Thanks! Good suggestion, it does clean up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have a javascript-free solution if you can bear with moving the links above the divs (or with some clever positioning).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XUwwY/

Concept:

```
.org:hover ~ #orginfo {
     visibility: visible;   
}
```

Comment: ya i was trying to figure out that technique lol. thanks a bunch i'll give this a go in a minute!